# how to Build the PhoneGap Sample Application Project for blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

I want to create application for `blackberry` using `phoneGap`, I have downlaoded & installed all required tools as given on this page

> http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-BlackBerry-WebWorks .

However, when I try to build (using [this link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-BlackBerry-WebWorks#BuildthePhoneGapSampleApplicationProject)) sample phoneGap project given for blackbery that comes with phoneGap library. I am getting this error

[image]

Where it gives message that `"C:\BBWP\bbwp.exe. not found, Please edit 'blackberry.bbwp.dir' in your 'project.properties' file."` and when I go to blackberry webworks sdk directory i.e. `C:\BBWP\` there is no `bbwp.exe` file please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Install the SDk properly... There should be a bbwp.exe file

Comment: i again downloaded and reinstalled webworks sdk but still same error is coming, plz see console for error at this link http://i45.tinypic.com/2uhpvz5.png 

even i editted "project.properties" file as given here http://i50.tinypic.com/2reks3d.png

plz help

Comment: i was able to solve the problem, webworks sdk which i had downloaded from blackberry website was beta version because that i think it has no bbwp.exe file. so later i downloaded a stable webworks sdk and it has bbwp.exe and this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the blackberry.xml file and change the bbwp property to use bbwp.bat instead of bbwp.exe:

```
<condition property="bbwp" value="${properties.blackberry.bbwp.dir}/bbwp" else="${properties.blackberry.bbwp.dir}/bbwp.exe">
    <equals arg1="${isMacOSX}" arg2="true" />
</condition>
```

change to

```
<condition property="bbwp" value="${properties.blackberry.bbwp.dir}/bbwp" else="${properties.blackberry.bbwp.dir}/bbwp.bat">
    <equals arg1="${isMacOSX}" arg2="true" />
</condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem downloading an older version of WebWorks SDK, not the BB 10 one. I found it at:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/previousversions/

Download the one labeled **WebWorks SDK for Smartphones Version 2.3** on Windows 7/8 open the installer in *Compatibility Mode - Win XP SP3*

It was a little tricky to find it. Hope it help others with the same problem. Don't forget it needs an JDK 1.6 of 32 bits even if your machine is 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

If you`re using the latest **BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15** or above, you should configure in this way

project.properties file :

```
blackberry.bbwp.dir=C:\\Program Files\\BlackBerry\\BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15\\
```

blackberry.xml :

```
<condition property="bbwp" value="${properties.blackberry.bbwp.dir}/bbwp" else="**${properties.blackberry.bbwp.dir}/webworks.bat**">
        <equals arg1="${isMacOSX}" arg2="true" />
    </condition>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -1):

You should downlod a SDK WebWorks compatible version to ant and phonegap.

I had the same problem and i downloaded the Smartphone SDK and the problem go away.

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/sdk

Cheers.